# getting my scrollIntoView working (total noob)

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to make an FAQ page using an accordion. In some of the answers I tried to make a clickable link, that will direct you to another question (I don't want the page to refresh).

With what I have now, the opened question (containing the link) will close the accordion after clicking, and open the desired accordion. The only thing missing is that the page will not scroll to the new question.

What I've got:

```
function openQuestion(q) {
    jQuery('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.accordion-container').fadeOut(500);
    var accordions = jQuery('.accordion-toggle');
    var accordion = accordions[q - 1];
    jQuery(accordion).addClass('active');
    jQuery(accordion).next('.accordion-container').slideToggle(500);
    }
```

I assume the next jquery line would contain something with scrollIntoView. But no succes yet.

This is what I use in HTML

```
<ahref="javascript:openQuestion(q)">text</a>
```

```
<div class="entry">
    <h3>FAQ</h3>
    <p>...</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="accordion wrapper">
        <h3 class="accordion toggle active">
            <a href="#">...</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="accordion-container" style="display: block;">
            <div class="content-block">
                <span style="font-weight: 400;">...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end accordion container -->
        <h3 class="accordion toggle">...</h3>
        <div class="accordion-container" style="display: none;">...</div>
        <!-- end accordion container -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: insert your css and more html, pls

Comment: I added some HTML, hope this is any useful. 
The site is not owned by me I'm only trying to add another page. The owner uses wordpress Udesign theme. Can see loads of css from the theme itself. Not sure what part might be of any use to you. I added no extra css on my specific page.
Thanks.
.

Comment: that's all your code gives you. it is difficult to help you seeing such a result. need css - https://ibb.co/4YfZDwg

Comment: do you need to scroll down when you click on a question?